# Get selected text from dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I am totally new in PHP, in fact the reason I am doing this is to customize a wordpress plugin so it can fit my need. So far I have a default form, what I am doing now is to add a country dropdown. Here's how I add it

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Country">Country :</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="itemType_id" name="cscf[country]" class="input-xlarge">
            <option value="malaysia@email.com">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="indonesia@email.com">Indonesia</option> 
        </select>   
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

So far I only able to retrieve the value of selected item with

```
$cscf['country'];
```

How can I get the display text which is the country name in this case ?

Comment: if u want to retireve value on other page then u will need form so u can use GET/POST methods for sending values from form to another page..

Comment: can you handle it by using if else? not the really best way though..

Comment: If you want to submit the text, then don't declare the `value` attributes in the option tags.  FYI: your `for` attribute doesn't relate to a `id` attribute anywhere in your provided script and therefore doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a hidden field, and with JavaScript and jQuery you can set the value to this field, when the selected value of your dropdown changes.

```
<select id="itemType_id" name="cscf[country]" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="malaysia@email.com">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="indonesia@email.com">Indonesia</option> 
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="country" id="country_hidden">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#itemType_id").change(function(){
      $("#country_hidden").val(("#itemType_id").find(":selected").text());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then when your page is submitted, you can get the name of the country by using

```
$_POST["country"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<select name="text selection" onchange="getText(this)">
  <option value="">Select text</option>
  <option value="1">my text 1</option>
  <option value="2">my text 2</option>
</select>
```

First put a java script function on the attribute "onchange" of the select.
Then, create your function that will transfer the text in a text box by using getElementById

```
<script>
  function getText(element) {
  var textHolder = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text
  document.getElementById("txt_holder").value = textHolder;
  }
</script>
```

Then create a temporary holder:

```
<input type="" name="txt_holder" id="txt_holder"> type should be hidden
```

Then assign it in a PHP variable:

```
$variableName=$_POST['txt_holder'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like,

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['save']))
   {
      //Let $_POST['cscf']['country']= malaysia@email.com
      // you can explode by @ and get the 0 index name of country
      $cnt=explode('@',$_POST['cscf']['country']);
      if(isset($cnt[0]))// check if name exists in email
         echo ucfirst($cnt[0]);// will echo Malaysia
   }
?>

<form method="post">
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="itemType_id" name="cscf[country]" class="input-xlarge">
            <option value="malaysia@email.com">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="indonesia@email.com">Indonesia</option> 
        </select>   
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" name='save' value="Save"/>   
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You still couldn't get the displayed text, only the value. You could tack the the text onto the value like `malaysia@email.com|Malaysia` and then `list($value, $text) = explode('|', $_POST['cscf']['country']); echo $text;`

Comment: Doesn't the post need to be `$cnt=explode('@',$_POST['cscf']['country']);`

Comment: @Casey, thanks. This answer will only work well if I followed your suggestion

Comment: @Rohan, your current answer will only work if the email address is always in the following format `<countryName>@email.com`. If the email address is in different format, I won't be able to get the country.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['save']))
   {
       $arrayemail = $_POST['cscf'];
       $mail =  $arrayemail['country'];
       $explode=explode('@',$mail);
      // print_r($explode);
        if(isset($explode[0]))
         echo ucfirst($explode[0]);     

   }
?>

<form method="post">
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="itemType_id" name="cscf[country]" class="input-xlarge">
            <option value="malaysia@email.com">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="indonesia@email.com">Indonesia</option> 
        </select>   
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" name='save' value="Save"/>   
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```