# Getting selected option value and text both

Tags: php, html

How do I get the option value and text both?

```
<label for="inputCourse" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Speakers</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" id="inputCourse" name="speaker">
        <option value="">--Select Speaker--</option>
        <?php foreach ($value as $key) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key['email']; ?>"> <?php echo $key['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `$value` is coming from PHP backend itself so in case you got `$key['email']` your can extract it from `$value`

Comment: where you want to get the value and text both? before or after form submit?

Comment: after submitting the form.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216971/get-selected-text-from-dropdown-in-php

Comment: you should use javascript or jquery to do that